# Is initramfs expandable when embedded in kernel?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, initramfs, busybox

If I embed initramfs in the kernel image, (I can do this by setting the config variable for the iniramfs file source location, and initramfs becomes located in  data section I guess), and after I boot and get into shell, (by the way I made the initramfs.cpio.gz using busybox) can I make a file in the file system ? I mean does initramfs get expanded as some files are populated there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[initramfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk#Implementation) is a compressed CPIO archive, it gets transparently mounted and it's basically read-only for all intents and purposes. You cannot edit/expand it, only recreate it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my experiment in FPGA, the boot process stops while executing /bin/sh(which is launched by the last command of /init script). I embedded initramfs in the kernel Image. Can this be the cause of the problem by any chance?(maybe some process tryng to write something in the file system? This happens if run a program printing hello repeateadly. It stops after ~ 190 times.) Though it looks like the uart rx interrupt doesn't happen...

Comment: @ChanKim um, that seems pretty unlikely to be related.